# Authorization through Yahoo

Tags: php, api, redirect, authorization, yahoo

I had a problem when authorizing a user through yahoo, I followed step by step as in the [documentation](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/flows_authcode/), but got stuck at step 2, when I tried to specify my method in redirect_uri, the following message appeared in the browser window:

"Uh oh
Looks like something went wrong.
Please try again later. "

in url address

https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth_fe?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&response_type=code&state=STATE

What I doing wrong?

Comment: In the documentation, the endpoint is listed as `request_auth`, not `request_auth_fe`. Is that potentially the issue?

Comment: thanks for your attention

I am getting request_auth_fe when following a dialog link as a response in the url address bar

The authorization link (dialogue) looks like this
https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?client_id=$id&redirect_uri=$uri&response_type=code&state=$state&language=en-us